# gorm.Model CreatedAt and UpdatedAt have unexpected date after querying the postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

If I look at the database I can see this

```
2023-03-19 16:26:07.382 -0300
2023-03-19 16:26:07.382 -0300
```

After querying, those times become these.

```
"CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
```

I'm using GORM with Postgres and my user struct is this

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uint        `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name        string      `json:"name" gorm:"not null"`
    LastName    string      `json:"last_name" gorm:"not null"`
    Email       string      `json:"email" gorm:"not null; unique;"`
    Password    string      `json:"password" gorm:"not null"`
    Bday        time.Time   `json:"bday" time_format:"sql_datetime" gorm:"nullable"`
    Gender      string      `json:"gender" gorm:"nullable"`
    Address     []Address   `gorm:"nullable"`
    Phones      []Phone     `gorm:"nullable"`
    OwnedEvents []Event     `gorm:"nullable; foreignkey:OwnerID;"`
    Invites     []User      `gorm:"nullable; many2many:event_guests;"`
    Colaborator Colaborator `gorm:"nullable;"`
}
```

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: To your question add the answers to: 1) I don't see `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` in your model, so are they fields Gorm adds to the table to track INSERT and UPDATE respectively? 2) What is the query you use to get the values `2023-03-19 16:26:07.382 -0300`? 3) What code are you using to get  the values `"CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"` and `"UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver he embedded the `gorm.Model` struct, which contains `ID`, `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt` and `DeletedAt`.

Comment: As you can see I duplicated the ID field. I removed it and now query by the embeded struct: like this 
`db.First(&user, models.User{Model: gorm.Model{ ID: 1,},})` 
With this, the embeded fields "CreatedAt" and "UpdatedAt" are beeing returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed your goal with the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string
    LastName string
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})

    var user User
    db.First(&user, 1)
    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(&user, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

I simplified the version of the `User` struct just to focus only on the dates which caused you trouble.
When I ran the code, I got the following output:

```
{
        "ID": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2023-03-20T10:24:51.590119+01:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2023-03-20T10:24:51.590119+01:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Name": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"
}
```

Now, you're ready for converting the `User` struct into another one or to better format the dates (maybe in a shorter way).
Furthermore, be sure to double-check the database if the record was correctly set.
Please, let me know if this solves your issue!